# Getting Records from Table in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have this requirement where I have to check the data based on data given in other fields. I have table with 'N' fields. I should allow user to select 4 fields which are from the table. And then I should get all other fields of that particular record and display it to the user so that he can verify that the data he entered into table is correct. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your post and give us an example? Also, what specific problem do you have? Where is your code breaking?

Comment: To the down-voters: If you don't tell the OP what they did wrong, why bother downvoting?

Comment: So I have an entry form for entering data into table. The user now wants to check the data after entering it. For checking, they would like to select four fields already present in the table and other fields should show up.   Ex: Lets say a Form has 4 fields - FirstName (Primary), LastName(Primary), DOB(Primary), Gender. Now the user want to check the data he entered. So I need to form Checking form which is similar to Entry form. I will allow user to select from Primary Keys - Combo for FirstName, Combo for LastName and Combo for DOB - Gender value for this user should be shown up.

Comment: You seem to be new. When you need to add a large amount of relevant information to your question, it would be better to edit that information into the original. You should also rephrase so it is a little more clear what you have, what you are trying to do, and what it is that isn't working - even if that means the question runs a little long.

Answer (score 0):

I have a clearer understanding now of what you require - hopefully this is what you need:

---

Assume you have a table called 'Phones'

The phones table has three primary fields:  Manufacturer, Operating System, and Carrier
In addition to these primary fields there are secondary "spec" fields.  For now we have three:  ScreenSize, Frequencies, and Price.

I create a form with three combo boxes:  ManufacturerFilter, OperatingSystemFilter, and CarrierFilter.
Each combo box's row source is similar to:

```
SELECT Carrier FROM Phones GROUP BY Carrier ORDER BY Carrier;
```

Where Carrier is replaced by Manufacturer and [Operating System] respectively.

I then add in all of the secondary fields, each bound to their own respective field.

You can also add in a button called "Retrieve"  for now leave the click code blank.

---

At this point you have a few options.  I'll highlight two, but both options will require the following procedure:

```
Private Function FilterStr() As String
  Dim myFilterStr As String

  ' Include each filter if they are entered
  If Nz(Me.ManufacturerFilter, "") <> "" Then myFilterStr = myFilterStr & "[Manufacturer]='" & Me.ManufacturerFilter.Value & "' AND"
  If Nz(Me.OperatingSystemFilter, "") <> "" Then myFilterStr = myFilterStr & "[Operating System]='" & Me.OperatingSystemFilter.Value & "' AND"
  If Nz(Me.CarrierFilter, "") <> "" Then myFilterStr = myFilterStr & "[Carrier]='" & Me.CarrierFilter.Value & "' AND"

  ' Remove the last AND statement
  If myFilterStr <> "" Then myFilterStr = Mid(myFilterStr, 1, Len(myFilterStr) - 4)
  FilterStr = myFilterStr
End Function
```

This function returns a filter string, based on the combo box options selected.

**Option #1: Filter the Recordset**
What we want to occur, is when a primary field value is selected, the records are filtered to display only those matching the criteria.  Add the following code to the OnClick event of your Retrieve button:

```
Private Sub RetreiveButton_Click()
  Dim myFilterStr As String
  myFilterStr = FilterStr

  If myFilterStr <> "" Then
    Me.Filter = myFilterStr
    Me.FilterOn = True
  Else
    Me.Filter = ""
    Me.FilterOn = False
  End If
End Sub
```

So what happens when the button is clicked, is that a filter string is created based on the values selected, and then a filter is applied to the form.   If no values are selected in the combo boxes, the filter is cleared and turned off.

**Option #2: Find a Record based on the Value**
What we want is to select the values in the comboboxes, and then move to the record that matches the criteria.

Add the following code to the onClick event of the retrieve button.

```
Private Sub RetreiveButton_Click()
  Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
  Dim myFilterStr As String

  myFilterStr = FilterStr()

  If myFilterStr = "" Then
    MsgBox "No Filter Selected", vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
  rst.FindFirst myFilterStr
  If rst.NoMatch Then
    MsgBox "No Matching Records were found", vbOKOnly, "No Data"
  Else
    Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
  End If

  Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

This uses the the same FilterStr() function to return a search string, but uses the recordset's FindFirst method to locate a record.  If found, it will move to the record.

Hope that answers your question.  As I indicated, the exact behaviour will vary but the underlying principle remains the same.

Comment: Hey DHW...thanks for the suggestion...But the entry and checking has to be done for records after they are entered...Entry and checking is done multiple times...If I use the above approach the user has to check all the records again coz he can't select a specific record.

Comment: Let me try to elaborate what I am trying to do - I have an entry form. The data is entered into the table through this. Now I am providing the user the primary fields. So these are combo boxes which get data from table. When the user selects all the primary keys it is similar to pulling up a record(fields other than lookup fields) using a query. Just that I should be able to show the retrieved fields in thier respective textboxes. I have been trying to work on this for a long time. But not sure how to go ahead.

Comment: I think I got you - You want to lookup the record using its primary keys and then display the records.   Let me modify my answer with a solution for you.  Give me a bit to write the code.

Comment: Thanks...Will try out the appraoch